# How to get ID attribute value of 3rd parent up

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to capture the value of the ID attribute of the 3rd parent up when a link is clicked.
Example:

```
<div id="First Div">
  <div class="class A">
    <div class="class B"></div>
    <div class="class C"></div>
    <div class="class D">
        <i class="link A">Clickable Element</i>
    </div>   
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to store the value "First Div" in a variable when "Clickable Element" is clicked.

Comment: Just want to remind you, <div id="First Div"> has two IDs, you might want an underscore between them like First_Div

Comment: You're right, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the `id` should not contain spaces add underscore instead.

You could attach click event to the class `link` and on click go up to the parent who has an attribute `id` and save it in variable :

```
$('.link').on('click', function(){
    var id_attribute=$(this).closest('div[id]').prop('id');
})
```

Hoep this helps.

---

```js
$('.link').on('click', function(){
    var id_attribute=$(this).closest('div[id]').prop('id');
    
    alert(id_attribute);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="First_Div">
  <div class="class A">
    <div class="class B"></div>
    <div class="class C"></div>
    <div class="class D">
        <i class="link A">Clickable Element</i>
    </div>   
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using:

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().attr("id");
```

but it's not a nice solution, because you need to make sure those parents actually exist.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the parents() method of jquery which will traverse up the DOM until it finds a match.

```
$(this).parents().find('div#First_div').attr('id');
```

http://api.jquery.com/parents/

Comment: The id of the div is `First div`